# Get value of a table data on button click

Tags: php, html

[image]

I am building a online exam application, here paper name and no. of papers are retrieved from database. Now I want to get the paper code of that paper for which I clicked the start button. Code for the table is here:

```
          <form method="post" action="exam_page.php" >
           <table >
                <tr style="background-color: #7F859E;color:white; height:50px;">
                     <th style="padding-left:140px; width:550px;">Paper</th> 
                     <th style="padding-left:40px;">Time</th>
                     <th style="padding-left:40px;">Duration</th>
                     <th style="padding-left:40px; width:250px;"></th>
                      
                </tr>
                <?php
                     $i=1;
                     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){?>
                     <tr style="height:80px; background-color: #CCCCCC;">
                          <td style="padding-left:40px;"> 
                               <input type="text" value="<?=$row['paper_code']?>" name="paper_code<?=$i?>" readonly><?=$row['paper_name']?>
                          </td>
                          <td style="padding-left:40px;">
                               <input type="text" value="<?=$row['time']?>" readonly style="width:90px;">
                          </td>
                          <td style="padding-left:40px;">
                               <input type="text" value="<?=$row['duration']?> Min" readonly style="width:90px;">
                          </td>
                          <td style="padding-left:40px;"><button style="width:100px;">Start</button></td>
                     </tr>
                <?php $i++; } $_SESSION['exam']=$i; ?>
            </table>
          </form>
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: will keep it in mind from next time... :)

Comment: Is there a `<form>` tag around the table?

Comment: Also, any reason you're using inputs to display the time and duration if they're readonly? Will they be editable at some point?

Comment: I need the value of time and duration in my next page...so i used inputs to get the value of those on button click

Answer (score 1):

Name your submit button, (also make it a submit type) and assign the paper code to its value attribute.

```
<button type="submit" style="width:100px;" name="clicked" value="<?=$row['paper_code']?>">
    Start
</button>
```

Now, in `exam_page.php` you can get the value of the clicked button from `$_POST['clicked']`. (Or whatever you decide to name it.)

---

To get the values from the other inputs associated with the button you clicked, you can add the paper code to their names instead of using `$i`.

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$row['time']?>" name="time[<?=$row['paper_code']?>]">
```

and in `exam_page.php` you can get the value from `$_POST['time'][$_POST['clicked']]`, etc.

If they aren't intended to be editable in your form, though, I would recommend using something else to display them and just loading them from the database in `exam_page.php` instead. Otherwise, your users will be able to override the `readonly` attribute and submit different values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript onclick functions:

```
<script>
   function getPaperCode(paperCode)
   {
      alert(paperCode);
   }

</script>
```

Then edit your input add onclick event:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['paper_code']; ?>" onclick="getPaperCode('<?php echo $row["paper_code"]; ?>');" name="paper_code<?php echo $i; ?>" readonly><?=$row['paper_name']?>
```

Once you click. it will alert the value of the button

Answer (score 0):

passed your unique id value or examcode via hidden field like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['eid']?>">
```

and on button click perform query like

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
select * from table_name where id='$id';
```

Comment: This can work if there is a separate form for each row, but in this case there is one form around multiple rows of values, so if you do it this way, only the value from the last row will be in `$_POST['id']`.

Comment: oh,ok then may be data attribute is helpful: read this link [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)